# Give style for &raquo;

Tags: php, html, css

How can I write style for this characters: `&raquo;`
Is it possible? Or I have to write `<span class="class_name">&raquo;</span>` to style this symbol? Thank you.

Comment: You can't define styles for entities, afaik. Only tags, classes and ids - so yes, define a span, or apply your style requirements to the whole of the current block.

Answer (score 1):

You can not style individual symbols with CSS, so as you say, you would have to wrap it in a span or other styleable element and select on that.

Answer (score 1):

You can't select pieces of text with CSS. Only elements and pseudo-elements. Depending on context, [`:first-letter`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#first-letter) has the best hope of being able to match that.

You will probably have to add an element to select. It doesn't have to be a span or have a class.

It is possible that using `<q>` and then adding the quote character itself with `:before` / `:after` would be a better approach.